# Is it correct in projectile motion tangential and normal acceleration changes, whereas the net acceleration remains constant ($g$)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, coordinate-systems, vectors, projectile

If we think of projectile motion as a general curvilinear motion, the magnitude of tangential acceleration is given by $g sinθ$, and magnitude of normal acceleration is given by $g cosθ$, where $θ$ is the angle made by the velocity vector at that point with $x$-axis. θ does not remain constant as velocity vector changes direction. So normal acceleration and tangential acceleration do not remain constant. But their vector resultant is constant(**g**). How? Do they increase or decrease in such a way that their vector sum always remain constant?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The tangential and normal components of the acceleration are orthogonal, so by the Pythagorean theorem, the magnitude of the resultant acceleration is
$$\sqrt{(g \cos \theta)^2 + (g \sin \theta)^2} = g\sqrt{\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2\theta}=g.$$